# Recognizing a moving object with Azure Spatial Anchors

Tags: azure-spatial-anchors

Can (or will) Azure Spatial Anchors assist in Object Recognition? The service already stores a point cloud of a scanned area and later recognizes it - couldn't it also store the point cloud of a moving object and later assist in recognizing that object?

One example use case: recognizing a large piece of equipment that moves around, perhaps a vehicle.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, Azure Spatial Anchors doesn't do this, but this is great feedback for our roadmap. If you are looking to build and deploy a solution around this or want to tell us more about the specific scenario please email azuremrs@microsoft.com